# Sapui5 app not uglified using grunt

Tags: gruntjs, sapui5

I'm trying to uglify ( mangle + remove comments ) a SapUI5 app by using grunt together with the `grunt-sapui5-bestpractice-build` plugin.

According to this [link](https://www.sap.com/developer/tutorials/webide-grunt-basic.html), there should not be an uglify task by using this plugin so I've combine it together with the `grunt-contrib-uglify` plugin.

The problem that I have is; when performing the application build, it seems that my `uglify` task is being ignored because the `grunt-sapui5-bestpractice-build` has an implicit `uglify` task that overwrites the one I'm defining.

For a better understanding, this is the code:

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "grunt-build",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Grunt build",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
      "@sap/grunt-sapui5-bestpractice-build": "1.3.33",
      "grunt-contrib-uglify": "3.3.0"
   }
}
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  'use strict';
    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        uglify: {
            options: {
                mangle: true,
                compress: {
                    drop_console: true,
                    dead_code: false,
                    unused: false
                }
            },
            files: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: "<%= ref.staging%>",
                src: ["**/*.js", '!test/**', '!test_local.html'],
                dest: "<%= ref.process%>"
            }
        }
    }); 

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('@sap/grunt-sapui5-bestpractice-build');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'lint',
        'clean',
        'build',
        'uglify'
    ]);
};
```

The result is that the application is correctly built & minified, Component-preload.js is created ad used to load the app but the mangle is not done and the comments are still there.

Could you kindly provide any advice here? Do you have any way to input the grunt-sapui5-bestpractice-build with the mangle option in order to do it just using one plugin?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would uglify before I'd build, because the resulting preload file is all strings and not straight up JS. You might need a copy action in between, you don't want to mangle your source files

Comment: Hi Jorg, thanks for your response.

Comment: Are you sure this is not done already? I just had a peek in the `dist` folder of an app and while I didnt look very closely, I did see the minified `Component.js` file and the unminified `Component-dbg.js` file.

Comment: Hi Jorg, I must have done something wrong because I though I had published my comment but it seems that I just published one part, let me reply to both your replies. I've tried using first uglify option but result is the same. Regarding the copy option, I¨'ve seen it used around but I don't have a clear vision of how it could be used, could you provide info here? The mangle option was being used just to clearly see that "my defined" tasks were being executed, once this works it will be discussed if useful or not.

Comment: Regarding your second comment, you're right, Component-preload.js is created and loaded within the application execution but if you check it in the chrome dev.tools, it's just minified. What I expect to see ( as I'm using the compress and the mangle option in my uglify task ) is that comments are removed and variables names are changed. Thanks a lot everyone for your advice

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an extended comment, and not a fully functional answer. I just ran out of space.

The advantage of having the `Component-preload.js` *not* mangled is that you can debug it normally, because it contains the spaces, comments etc. Debugging mangled code is more difficult.

You'll have to look at the things you need to do to accomplish this mangling. After `'@sap/grunt-sapui5-bestpractice-build'` is done, you have minified but not mangled `Component.js`, a minified but not mangled `Comonponent-preload.js` and a normal development version in `Component-dbg.js`, correct?

You might want to abandon the best practice package and go for something else entirely like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-openui5. I can't see what happens in the steps in `'@sap/grunt-sapui5-bestpractice-build'`, I can't even find that package anywhere.

Grunt is only executing a series of tasks in a row. I haven't tried the webIDE versions of this but here's the list of tasks I'm executing as part of an offline openui5 app:

```
'clean:build', // remove `build` folder
'clean:dist',  // remove `dist` folder
'copy:build',  // copy all my code to the `build` folder
'preload',     // mangle all my code in the `build` folder and create a preload
'copy:dist:minified', // copy the mangled code to `dist`
'copy:dist:dbg',      // copy and rename my original code as `-dbg.js` versions to `dist`
'clean:build' // remove the `build` folder
```

This was done with gulp, using packages gulp-openui5-preload and gulp-uglify and some others. Not sure if gulp works on the web ide, but I think you can recreate this in Grunt.

You can either use something like this to mangle the results of the default process and create a new preload file, or you can scrap the default and try to roll your own entirely.